# how do I show the kmeans' cluster centre on a plot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, k-means

I use K-means clustering in python to cluster my data. it has 10 clusters and I want to show the cluster centers on the plot but I do not know how can I add these centers to the output plot. my code to produce the K-means is as follows:

```
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaled_features = pd.DataFrame((psnr_bitrate))
kmeans = KMeans(init="random",n_clusters=10,n_init=10,max_iter=300,random_state=42)
kmeans.fit(scaled_features)

scaled_features['cluster'] = kmeans.predict(scaled_features)
pd.plotting.parallel_coordinates(scaled_features, 'cluster')
```

the plot is as follows:
[image]

now I need to add cluster's center on this output plot. could you please tell me how can I do this? the cluster's center is as follows:

```
27.1396 30.5737 32.6351 34.1704 35.491  36.671
30.814  34.4368 36.5749 38.1478 39.4876 40.6812
47.4692 51.1455 53.2468 55.0004 56.4387 57.4467
41.6078 45.9204 48.1359 49.5386 50.7643 51.722
61.6059 67.1973 70.1847 72.5432 74.2267 76.0297
35.0321 38.431  40.3014 41.6793 42.8545 43.8871
52.9523 57.7112 60.7287 62.9767 64.5461 65.7331
20.4673 22.7256 24.422  25.8274 27.1183 28.5281
38.0638 41.6465 43.5892 44.9946 46.2122 47.2814
24.1948 27.1877 29.0956 30.5446 31.8271 33.0845
```

scaled features are a dataframe with size 1297x7. some samples are as follows:

```
31.7648 35.6328 38.0885 39.8772 41.3319 42.9237 1
29.8327 34.5675 37.5274 39.621  41.4125 43.0239 1
36.7771 41.1513 44.1225 46.2371 47.8790 49.8322 8
46.8715 52.0063 54.7845 57.0994 58.7678 60.6746 2
33.7730 36.1712 38.0328 39.5894 40.9371 42.2142 1
45.8674 49.2719 51.4785 53.2475 54.9812 56.5073 2
48.4214 51.8488 54.3905 56.6877 58.4573 60.0295 2
48.7905 52.6913 55.5347 57.7932 59.9531 61.5385 2
21.18   24.2885 26.4587 27.9518 29.077  30.0572 7
21.6955 24.7870 26.6992 28.0166 28.995  29.9046 7
22.7463 25.9799 27.8511 29.1185 30.3565 31.7200 9   
21.9152 24.8177 26.8574 28.2361 29.4645 30.6062 7
```

Thank you.

Comment: Just take the average of each cluster

Comment: could you please explain more? I am not familiar with python and Kmeans a lot. why should I average each cluster? I have the centroids but I do not know how can I show them in the plot.

Comment: I thought you didn't. So your question is just about plotting. Can you provide same sample data in the form of a dataframe

Comment: yes. my problem is about plotting and I need to show the cluster centroids on the plot. psnr_bitrate is a NumPy array with size  1297x6 .

Comment: Just provide some sample data of scaled_features

Comment: I put an example of scaled_features above